# Customize New tab page in chrome for android

Tags: android, google-chrome

I am thinking of building a new tab page for chrome which works for both desktop and mobile devices. I know that the chrome extensions do not work for mobile devices but the mobile app can be integrated with other apps on the mobile device as found [here](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/overview). Hence, I was thinking whether an android app can be used as a workaround which overrides the new tab page. Is this possible? If yes, how?

Comment: Make some sort of a web-page using JavaScript, and ask your users to set it as their homepage, if this is feasible

Comment: Chrome for android doesn't have the concept of a home page unlike android stock browser. I searched about that too before posting the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is not possible if the Google chrome does not provide you an API for that. It is because all the Android applications are prepared to be as a single app package that can't know anything about other apps but the things the OS (Android) provides to them. For example, you can query the OS to know what apps can answer to a question (`Intent`) like: "Who can open an email?".

Imagine what would happen if what you want could be possible. I am an attacker that for some reason wants to inject a behavior in another app. This app can't have the control of what it is doing anymore and we can inject, bypass permissions or whatever, without the user agreement.

However, some kind of modifications of this type can be done by adding some files in a rooted device. Anyway, this is a complex situation and something that cannot suit your needs.